# Ao aplicar um duplo clique sobre a imagem da bola uma cópia da imagem seja inserida em uma das divs aleatoriamente utilizando esse trecho de codigo

Tags: javascript, html5

```
    <body>
        <div id="princ">
            <div class="princ" id="header"></div>

            <div id="div1" class="interna">DIV 1</div>
            <div id="div2" class="interna">DIV 2</div>
            <div id="div3" class="interna">DIV 3</div>
            <div id="div4" class="interna">DIV 4</div>
            TEXTO:<input type="text" id="txtTeste">
            <input type="button" id="btOk" value="ok"><br>
            COR DE FUNDO:<input type="color" id="clrCor">
            <div id="divBola"><img src="imagens/bola.jpg" alt="bola" id="bola"> 
 </div>
            <div id="rodape">Rodapé</div>
        </div>      
        <script src="js/funcoes.js">
        </script>
    </body>
-----script-----


var bol = document.getElementById("bola");

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("interna");


bol.ondblclick = function(){

   var I = parseInt(Math.random()*3);

};
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida, erro, ou dificuldade?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente você insere um template dentro da div

```js
    var bol = document.getElementById("bola");
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("interna");
    bol.onclick = function(){
        var I = parseInt(Math.random()*4);
        x[I].innerHTML = '<img src="http://gorilaclube.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/181368-292-292/44005108-Cofrinha-bola-de-futebol.jpg" width="100" alt="bola" id="bola">';
    };
```

```html
<div id="princ">
        <div class="princ" id="header"></div>
        <div id="div1" class="interna">DIV 1</div>
        <div id="div2" class="interna">DIV 2</div>
        <div id="div3" class="interna">DIV 3</div>
        <div id="div4" class="interna">DIV 4</div>
        TEXTO:<input type="text" id="txtTeste">
        <input type="button" id="btOk" value="ok"><br>
        COR DE FUNDO:<input type="color" id="clrCor">
        <div id="divBola"><img src="http://gorilaclube.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/181368-292-292/44005108-Cofrinha-bola-de-futebol.jpg" width="100" alt="bola" id="bola"> 
        </div>
    <div id="rodape">Rodapé</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Tem como explicar porque x[i]

Comment: @Arquiro O `x[I]` irá selecionar uma `div.interna` aleatória.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro altere o valor no `Math.random()` de `3` para `4`, assim o valor gerado será de `0` a `3`, que será a referência para pegar a `id` das `div`s.

Depois você pode clonar o elemento `img` da bola e fazer um `appendChild`. Também criei uma variável `bolid` que é incrementada a cada clonagem para gerar um `id` único para cada nova imagem, já que **um `id` deve ser único na página**:

```js
var bol = document.getElementById("bola");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("interna");
var bolid = 0; // variável para gerar ids
bol.ondblclick = function(){
   var I = parseInt(Math.random()*4);
   var clone = bol.cloneNode();
   clone.id += bolid++; // atribuir um id único
   document.getElementById("div"+(I+1)).appendChild(clone);
};
```

```html
<div id="princ">
   <div class="princ" id="header"></div>

   <div id="div1" class="interna">DIV 1</div>
   <div id="div2" class="interna">DIV 2</div>
   <div id="div3" class="interna">DIV 3</div>
   <div id="div4" class="interna">DIV 4</div>
   TEXTO:<input type="text" id="txtTeste">
   <input type="button" id="btOk" value="ok"><br>
   COR DE FUNDO:<input type="color" id="clrCor">
   <div id="divBola"><img height="50" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="bola" id="bola"> 
   </div>
   <div id="rodape">Rodapé</div>
</div>
```